# How can I make a C++ GUI with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have previously asked a question similar to this. I want to make a c++ program in visual studio that allows me to make a GUI. So, how would I go about configuring this in Visual Studio 2015? However, I want the language to be C++, not C++/CLI. Can you even use C++ for this? Thank you.

Comment: Using C++ and not C++/CLI what I am seeing is that the two main roads are to use MFC or a Universal App which seems to be Windows 10 oriented. Most of my experience has been with MFC. If your application is a desktop type of app and you don't mind the MFC look and feel, it can be a fairly productive GUI development environment. There are also non-Microsoft libraries such as the WTL or [Windows Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library)

Comment: I am currently investigating some alternatives to MFC. I am looking for a way to create a modern looking GUI app along the lines of some of the apps that come with Windows 8 and Windows 10 with the rich interfaces mixing graphics and animation. I am also wanting to incorporate some of the new mouse/gesture actions that are now available with tablets and other touch type interfaces.

Comment: There is a sample application source code from Microsoft, originally with VS 2010, that can be installed through Visual Studio (File -> New -> Project -> Online -> Samples -> Visual C++) with documentation available through [Hilo: Developing C++ Applications for Windows 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff708696(v=MSDN.10).aspx) which shows using DirectX techniques. "The Hilo sample applications are designed for high performance and responsiveness and are written entirely in C++ using Visual C++."

Comment: The Hilo demo is a photograph browser. I have pulled down the Hilo demo using Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 10 PC that has quite a few images in various folders, recompiled it, and used the browser application. It looks awesome! And there is functionality to communicate with flickr.com using WinHTTP to upload photos as well. So there seems to be a lot to learn from this sample.